# [name]Controller and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "createReturnableUrl"

Tags: php, yii

Working in Yii, I get this error:

> SystemManagementController and its behaviors do not have a method or
> closure named "createReturnableUrl"

I can not find anything to solve it. it happened right after I added this:

```
array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            //'viewButtonUrl' => '$this->grid->controller->createReturnableUrl("view",array("id"=>$data->id))',
            'updateButtonUrl' => '$this->grid->controller->createReturnableUrl("update",array("id"=>$data->id))',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => '$this->grid->controller->createReturnableUrl("delete",array("id"=>$data->id))',
            //'deleteConfirmation' => Yii::t('app', 'Are you sure to delete this item?'),
        ),
```

to :

```
<?php
    //The following lines needs to be moved to the controller to separate the view from the controllers.
    $model = new CActiveDataProvider('User');

    //The following line should be set by the controller. Containing the names of the columns in a chosen language.
    /**/

    $colums = array(
        'login',
        'name_first',
        'name_last',
        
        //'password',
        'email',
        'is_active',
        //'sortorder',
        array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            //'viewButtonUrl' => '$this->grid->controller->createReturnableUrl("view",array("id"=>$data->id))',
            'updateButtonUrl' => '$this->grid->controller->createReturnableUrl("update",array("id"=>$data->id))',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => '$this->grid->controller->createReturnableUrl("delete",array("id"=>$data->id))',
            //'deleteConfirmation' => Yii::t('app', 'Are you sure to delete this item?'),
        ),
    );


    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $model,
        'columns' => $colums,
        'filter' => $model->model)
    );
?>
```

When I remove that piece of code, there is not problem, everything works, but when I add that line it gives me the error.

I use that line in a different class as well and there I don't get the problem, how can I get rid of this?

Comment: try to escape the $, that might just fix it.

Comment: @MihaiP. i did remove the $ it works now but I get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /vagrant/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/base/CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Comment: the other controllers that are using this, are all of them (including the problem controller) extending the same class?

Comment: wwell, they dont show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the controller does not know about createReturnableUrl. From what I googled that is a behavior of yii that you can attach, are you sure you attached the behavior properly for the SystemManagementController? See if all the other controller that work with the same code have that behavior attached, maybe this one does not.